# MySQL PHP Get value from a database when knowint two other values in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table - In my problem I have two values which I know each in a separate column, but I need to find the 3 value based on the two values that I know and echo it.

This is what I tried but no luck:

```
<?php
...

$profile_url = 'xyz';

$pic_switch = array (
    '01' => mysql_query("SELECT mm_image_switch FROM $tbl_name04 WHERE profile_url = '$profile_url' AND mm_image_id ='01'")
    '02' => mysql_query("SELECT mm_image_switch FROM $tbl_name04 WHERE profile_url = '$profile_url' AND mm_image_id ='02'")
    '04' => mysql_query("SELECT mm_image_switch FROM $tbl_name04 WHERE profile_url = '$profile_url' AND mm_image_id ='04'")
...
?>
```

I want to get the value of the row mm_image_switch when the profile_url is xyz, and mm_image_id = 01, etc...

When I echo $pic_switch['01'] - i only get the profile_url value.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` does not return the value of `mm_image_switch`, it returns a [`resource`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), something you will pass as parameter to other functions like `mysql_fetch_row()` to iterate through the results of this query. You have to do something more like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT mm_image_switch FROM ...");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

if ($row !== FALSE) // if the query actually returned a matching row
{
    $pic_switch['01'] = $row['mm_image_switch'];
}
else
{
    $pic_switch['01'] = 'Not found';
}
```

But instead of doing one query for each ID, you can simply do this:

```
function get_pic_switches($profile_url, $ids)
{
    global $tbl_name04;

    $ret = array();
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT mm_image_id, mm_image_switch FROM $tbl_name04 WHERE profile_url = '$profile_url' AND mm_image_id IN ('".implode("', '", $ids)."')");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        $ret[$row[0]] = $row[1]; // $ret[mm_image_id] = mm_image_switch;
    }

    return $ret;
}

$pic_switch = get_pic_switches('xyz', array('01', '02', '04'));
```

Notice that the extension `mysql_` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in future versions of PHP. It is recommended that new code is written using one of its alternatives such as [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query doesn't return a value but a result set which can be read with others functions like mysql_fetch_row, mysql_fetch_assoc, mysql_fetch_object or mysql_fetch_array for example. See the php documentation (php.net) to get more details.

Otherwise, I don't understand why execute all of your queries in an array and why do you use an array for the same query with differents params values.

NB : mysql_* functions are deprecated. Prefer use the equivalents mysqli_* functions or PDO.